# Find and select specific changes between two object lists

Tags: c#, list, object, properties, compare

I have two lists of object T. Each T has unique key "T.key"

```
List<T> List1;
List<T> List2;
```

I want to create a list of keys of all the objects that are only in List2 but also ones that are in both lists but have specific property differences (lets name them T.a and T.b). Also the list contents are not necessarily in the same order.

Example input/output:

```
List1 = {{key:1,a:10,b:10,c:10}, {key:2,a:10,b:10,c:10}, {key:3,a:10,b:10,c:10}}
List2 = {{key:1,a:10,b:10,c:99}, {key:2,a:11,b:10,c:10}, {key:4,a:10,b:10,c:10}}

Result = {2,4}
```

Comment: the first half is pretty straightfoward, the second half of your question doesn't make much sense

Comment: Does "not in the two lists" mean "only in one list"?

Comment: I took "not in the two list" to mean, "not in `L2`".

Comment: Yeah I think some example data of the two input lists and what you expect for output would greatly clarify what's needed

Comment: OK your edit makes it pretty clear.

Comment: Just edited my post, I was confused myself

Comment: So you want to obtain all `T` that are not exactly identical between the lists, on all properties of `T`?

Comment: Only a and b, any other properties can change without putting the object in Result

Comment: One of the problems with an answer to the question is... which `T` do you return when property `T.a` or `T.b` has changed?

Comment: I changed it in my last edit, I want a list of key

Comment: OK also shouldn't your result contain 2,3 & 4?   Key 3 is not in your second list.

Comment: "I want to create a list of key of all the objects that are only in list2" 
I check only for new element and not those how are not present  anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this produces your expected output:

```
 List<T> list1 = new List<T> { new T { key = 1, a = 10, b = 10, c = 10 }, new T { key = 2, a = 10, b = 10, c = 10 }, new T { key = 3, a = 10, b = 10, c = 10 } };
 List<T> list2 = new List<T> { new T { key = 1, a = 10, b = 10, c = 99 }, new T { key = 2, a = 11, b = 10, c = 10 }, new T { key = 4, a = 10, b = 10, c = 10 } };

 List<int> difference = new List<int>();

 foreach (var item2 in list2)
 {
     var item1 = list1.FirstOrDefault(i => i.key == item2.key);

     if (item1 != null)
     {
         if (item2.a == item1.a && item2.b == item1.b)
             continue;
     }           

     difference.Add(item2.key);
 }
```

`difference` contains `{2,4}`

Answer (score 2):

A complete sample that produces the expected keys of: 2 and 4

```
List<F> L1 = new List<F>{new F(1,10,10,10), new F(2,10,10,10), new F(3,10,10,10)};
List<F> L2 = new List<F>{new F(1,10,10,99), new F(2,11,10,10), new F(4,10,10,10)}; 

void Main() { // Client code. One call covers the biz logic (and sample output)
    // Must call Except on L2 with L1 as the arg for proper eval of biz logic
    foreach ( var item in L2.Except(L1, new CompareListsOfObjsF()) ) 
        Console.WriteLine("key: " + item.key);  
}

class F { // Quick, dirty sample POCO w/ constructor
    public int key, a, b, c; 
    public F(int mk, int ma, int mb, int mc) { key=mk; a=ma; b=mb; c=mc; }
} 

class CompareListsOfObjsF : IEqualityComparer<F> {
    // business-specific equality logic - notice that 'c' is not evaluated
    public bool Equals(F x, F y) {
        return  x.key == y.key && x.a == y.a && x.b == y.b;
    }
    // The logic will not work without a proper hash function:
    public int GetHashCode(F x) { unchecked { // Overflow is ok
            int h = 17 * 23 + x.key;
            h += h * 23 + x.a;
            h += h * 23 + x.b;
            return h; // c has to be left out for selection biz logic to work
      }
   } 
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

> > key: 2
> >
> > key: 4

Comment: Nice... you beat me to it... I think this is the best answer given the updated question.  You might add that he could also build the `IEqualityComparer` into his `F` class.  Also `GetHashCode` should return the hashcode of the key, a, and b xor'd together or something along those lines.

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks for the kudos. I reorganized the sample and added some comments. The HashCode thing is a complete hack meant to satisfy the compiler. Its implementation has no effect for the OP. If the OP needs a well-functioning hash code then that's a separate question. :-) But I do agree that given the business rules, the POCO should contain the implementation of IEqualityComparer. In any case, the pieces are there, cleanly separated, for the OP to use at will.

Comment: yep I understand not wanting to drudge through the hashcode function... one thing... I'd add a note that IEquality comparer should implement GetHashCode if you intend to put them in a dictionary / hashtable / etc where you need a hashcode.

Comment: @Kevin: Oops... I was playing around with hashing and noticed that a hash function I lifted from one of Jon Skeet's famous answers produced an incorrect result. I was confused at first but realized that the Except function must use a Dictionary/HashSet in its implementation. So, lesson learned. Always to a proper impl. of GetHashCode. The hack of return the value 1 just happened to work!

Comment: Very good.  I'd vote it up but I already did.  Now that you mention it I realized I've run into that with Except before but it's been a while.  This is why you have to pass it an `IEqualityComparer` since it requires `GetHashCode()`

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks again. I saw you deleted your answer. Where was it going wrong? It seemed at least like a good start. I haven't played with the code.

Comment: Well I was grouping from both lists but since he didn't want items that were only in the first list it made more sense to switch to `.Except` and I saw you already had it covered.